# How to evade pursuit?

Tags: need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012

So in the old version of the game you had cooldown spots in which you could hide to evade. This new version I can't find any, so I have no choice but to drive super fast away, and then cruise trying to avoid police and loitering behind buildings, in tunnels and under construction sites.

What is an effective strategy for ending a police pursuit quickly? Ideally from any heat level, and using driving techniques. Rather than jumping to a race from EasyDrive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To lose the police you need to stay outside of their visual range long enough for your heat level to reset. It is simply a case of losing them, on the mini map you'll notice that while you're being pursued there is a visual range indicator;

[image]

Getting outside of that indicator will result in your heat level beginning to drop;

[image]

Once your heat level is below 5-6 bars you will enter initiate pursuit cooldown.

Once you're outside of the visual indicator and you've initiated pursuit cooldown, visiting a service station will reduce your heat level quicker as you pass through it. It will reduce your heat level once each time you go through it unless you've got 1 heat remaining, in which case it will immediately end the pursuit.

You can outrun them at low heat levels, but at higher heat levels you will need to utilise sharp corners, misdirection (ie: turning to go up an offramp or such like and then making a sudden turn that will send the police up the offramp while you drive on in a different direction) or causing accidents that block the road to give you some space.

You can also utilise the gameworld, by making jumps off ledges, smashing through billboards etc, which are routes that the police struggle to take properly. Another helpful trick is to turn your engine off while on cooldown. This greatly increases the rate at which your detection meter drops.

Comment: So there actually aren't any ingame mechanics for evading pursuit other than driving? I'm getting quite sick of 20 minute+ pursuits, and am consequently struggling to get gold in any of the Ambush races.

Comment: There are no 'cooldown spots' or similar from the previous games that I have found, no - but driving is a mechanic and that does exist in game! :P

Comment: How very disappointing. Almost as disappointing as finding out the whole game consists of only 5 races.

Comment: Well, there are a few more than five, as you get an additional set for each car (yes I know they're all essentially the same thing) + the 'boss' races

Comment: Also, switching cars when you are in cooldown immediately ends pursuit.

Comment: Parking causes the heat meter to reduce rapidly I found out from the tips today!

Answer (score 1):

There aren't a lot if your asking for tips.

A few are:

3. FULL NITROS!!
4. When you're far enough from the police, like just out of their sight circle (on the mini-map), try to take sharp turns and get behind buildings.
5. Listen when the police say something on the radio.